# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty na_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Prove that if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^ \infty na_n$ converges, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n$ converges.

No, $a_n$ are not necessarily positive numbers.

I've been trying summation by parts.

Comment: Think about what the summation converges to. If it converges to some real number then what would the sum of $n*a_n$ converge to?

Comment: I'd suggest writing $n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1$, then interchanging the order of summation on the partial sums. It should be clear what's happening to the terms to allow convergence.

Comment: @A.S. You can for the partial sums, since they're finite.

Comment: @Chap Then I get $\sum_{j=1}^N S_N-S_{j-1}$. I don't see how this is a simplification.

Answer (score 7):

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n ka_k$ with $S_0 = 0$ and $T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ then we have
$$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{S_k - S_{k-1}}{k} = \dfrac{S_n}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+1})S_k = \dfrac{S_n}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}S_k$$

Then it's clear that $T_n$ converges since $S_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is finite

Comment: That's a nice trick.

Comment: Concise and complete!  +1

Comment: Collapsing a telescoped term to show convergence is unnecessary (imagine if we had a general monotonically increasing unbounded positive $f(n)$ instead of $n$).

Comment: How did you get from the first summation to the second one?

Comment: @Jill_Johnson by checking coefficients before each $S_k$, since $S_k$ only appears in $\frac{S_{k+1} - S_k}{k+1}$ and  $\frac{S_{k} - S_{k-1}}{k}$

Comment: @A.S. indeed unnecessary, but sufficient for this problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Dirichlet's Test with {$na_n$} and {$1/n$}?

- Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ converges, the partial sums
  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ are bounded.
- $\lim \frac {1}{n} = 0$.
- The sequence $\frac {1}{n}$ is monotone, therefore the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lvert \frac {1}{n+1} - \frac   
     {1}{n}\right\rvert$ converges and the conditions hold for the test.
  So, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac {1}{n})(na_n)$=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: Jill, the series for the third bullet point ought not have absolute values around the summands.  - Mark

Comment: My textbook uses them. I think what I forgot was to place the absolute value signs are on the rest of the equation. I'll do that now.

Comment: No, I'm wrong, that won't work.

Comment: Actually, supposedly 1/n works because it is monotone and bounded below by zero.

Comment: I've changed it to reflect this.

Comment: Jill, all one needs here is that $\left|\sum_{k=1}^{K}k a_k\right|\le B$ for some $B$ for all $K\ge 1$; not sure as to the purpose of the telescoping series. - Mark