# How to prove or disprove - If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ both converge, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2a_n=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> My question is: whether the following is true or not, and how to prove in either case:
>
> $$\text{If}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n\quad\text{both converge, then}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}n^2a_n=0$$

There's no additional condition like $a_n$'s are positive, etc. (i.e. $a_n$ could be either positive or negative.)

(*) As a background, this question came to when I was solving this problem:
$$\text{If}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n=2\text{, then}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(a_n-a_{n+1})=?$$
that leads to estimate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2a_n-(n+1)^2a_{n+1})$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2a_n$.

Comment: How about reducing it to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}nb_n=0$$where $b_n=na_n$

Comment: [Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty na_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638349/prove-that-if-sum-n-1-infty-na-n-converges-then-sum-n-1-infty-a-n?rq=1) and [Series converges implies $\lim na_n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, your first comment, and the second link of your second comment, does not apply without additional hypotheses on $\{b_n\}$, like positive and nonincreasing.  For example, consider $b_n=\begin{cases} 1/n & \exists k\in \mathbb{N}, n=10^k\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: For the background question, I suppose that $a_n$ are positive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_n$ defined by $$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: :-) Yup, likely it is wanted that the terms are all positive, but idk...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Not really: "There's no additional condition like $a_n$'s are positive, etc. (i.e. $a_n$ could be either positive or negative.)"

Comment: Hence the "idk..." part, seeing as it was explicitly stated in the original post.

Comment: One probably needs positive *and* monotone for the proposed limit to hold now that I think about it.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best example.

Comment: @KayK. Probably the simplest, but [mechanodroid's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2420735/75808) is worth keeping in mind as well to see that non-negativity is not sufficient for the conclusion you wanted to hold.

Comment: Yeah, I can see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For an example where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ converge absolutely define the sequence $a_n$ as:

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n^2},  & \text{if $n$ is a perfect square} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

We have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4} < +\infty$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\cdot\frac{1}{k^4} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < +\infty$$

However,

$$n^2a_n = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ is a perfect square} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

so it does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$a_n=\frac {\sin (n)}{n^2} $$

$$\sum a_n $$  and $$\sum na_n $$ are convergent by Dirichlet's test , but
$$\lim n^2a_n \ne 0$$

Comment: =P Late to the party